# R combining multiple vectors created using dplyr's pull

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have monthly data for 2019, 2020 and only 2 months data for 2021 (Jan and Feb). I want to make a vector of these 26 values for use as a time series.

```
my_dat <- data.frame(X2021 = c(1:2,rep(NA,10)), X2020 = 1:12, X2019 = 1:12)
library(dplyr)
X2021 <- my_dat %>% pull(X2021)
X2021 <- X2021[ -(3:12) ]

x <- my_dat %>% pull(X2019,X2020)

c(x, X2021)

##1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12       
##1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2
```

I expected:

```
c(1:12, 1:12, 1:2)
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Please consider to attach a minimal reproducible example, recall this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Seems to work okay if you specify the frequency and start and end - `ts(1:26, frequency=12, start=c(2019,1), end=c(2021,2))`

Comment: @thelatemail ..Thank you! It works but the order of my vector gets messed up and some values are lost entirely. Here is my code:  in.sample<-ts(data=x, frequency=12, start=c(2019,1), end=c(2021,2)), where x is the vector of the 26 values. It only takes the 2019 values and keeps re-using those values

Comment: @user12715151 - i can't replicate your issue - I get the sequence 1-to-26, each one in a different month across the period specified. You're going to have to provide your `x` vector that you are inputting, and the output you are getting in the question above so we can get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: @thelatemail. i tested out the vector, it's length is 14 not 26 as I thought and each position , eg x[12] holds two values not one. Here is my code, sorry I tried but don't know how to format it like that -#Selecting only 2021: ` X2021<-my_dat %>% pull(X2021)
#deleting all months for which no actuals as yet, march onwards in this case
X2021<-X2021[-(3:12)]
X2021
#Creating vector of all actuals 
x<-my_dat %>% pull(X2019,X2020)

#26 data points of actuals in total, forecast for next 10 steps
x<-c(x,X2021)

in.sample<-ts(data=x, frequency=12, start=c(2019,1), end=c(2021,2))`

Comment: @thelatemail , I edited the question with the code!, the dataframe is my_dat from which i pulled the actuals for 2019, 2020 and 2021, which is what x is composed of

Comment: `x<-my_dat %>% pull(X2019,X2020)` doesn't do what you want. That is pulling `X2019`, and naming it with `X2020` - pull each year separately and then `c(...)` them together. You end up with 14 values because you have 12 (named) + 2. Do `pull(X2021)` `pull(X2020)` `pull(X2019` one at a time.

Comment: @thelatemail, thank you!!

Comment: @user12715151 - i've made an edit to your post which hopefully gets to the core of the issue, as I think it is actually a problem worth having answered. Please let me know if it looks okay.

Comment: @thelatemail   , looks good thanks!! Isn't there a more efficient way to combine multiple vectors not one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `pull` is equivalent to `$` in base R, and can only be used for extracting one variable, I think you want `select` and then `unlist`. E.g.:

```
my_dat %>% select(X2019, X2020) %>% unlist(use.names=FALSE)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Which would be equivalent to using the square brackets `[]` in base R:

```
unlist(my_dat[c("X2019","X2020")], use.names=FALSE)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

As to why the original code didn't work, `?pull` shows the syntax is:

```
pull(.data, var, name)
```

So

```
my_dat %>% pull(X2019,X2020)
```

is just pulling / extracting `X2019` and naming it with `X2020`. To give a clearer example:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=month.abb[1:3])
pull(dat, a, b)
#Jan Feb Mar 
#  1   2   3 
unname(pull(dat, a, b))
#[1] 1 2 3
names(pull(dat, a, b))
#[1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar"
```